# Problems Scraping with Selenium (xpath) in Tripadvisor

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am new in python and scraping.
I am trying to extract information about Tripadvisor. First of all, I need Selenium for crawling but when I run the program in diferents times the paths change.

I show you a example:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from _datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless=False
prefs={"profile.default_content_setting_values.notofications" :2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chromedriver = "C:/Users/rober/OneDrive/Escritorio/tfm/chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.es/")
//*[@id="component_5"]/div/div/div/span[3]/div/div/div/a/span[2]

#Click Restaurants
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="component_5"]/div/div/div/span[3]/div/div/div/a').click()

#Introduce localization
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW"]/div[14]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/input').send_keys("madrid")
```

In the last part of code, sometimes div[14] is div[13] or div[15]. is it possible absolute xpath or use other form?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use Xpath with a longer path. That makes the test brittle

Please use shorter xpaths. An Xpath like this "//input[@class="Smftgery"]" should help you click on the same input field.

[image]

Also to click on Restaurantes, you can use `//*[text()='Restaurantes']`

Comment: Thank you Seema!! You have helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your Xpath is too specific, find some uniqueness in the deeper levels of the DOM. This uniqueness can be also a combination of multiple levels.
e.g. if there is only one input field inside `BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW` you can ignore all the levels in between:
`'//*[@id="BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW"]//input'`

or use some other attribute of `input` e.g. if it has a `data` attribute:`//input[@data="the-data-of-the-input-field"]`